# How to count rows using group_by (that is not working)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (~350 rows) that looks like this

```
#df
Id  Species           blooming         Location  Tmax      Cmax
1    H. aureus          Yes               SP      29        35
2    H. impetoginosa    No                SP      34        28
3    H. ochraceus       Only last year    MS      32        27
4    H. roseoalba       Yes               DF      37        25

savanna=df %>%
  select(Species,  blooming, Location ) %>%
  filter(blooming=="Yes") %>%
  group_by(Location)
```

I confirmed that the Location variable is a factor. However, it is not grouping.

In addition, I do not know how can I count the rows that each Location has with "Yes" blooming (my final goal).

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please do **not** delete the data and replace it by an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with `count`. It has the advantage of grouping and counting all in one instruction.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(blooming == "Yes") %>%
  count(Location)
#  Location n
#1       DF 1
#2       SP 1
```

---

### Data

```
df <-
structure(list(Id = 1:4, Species = c("H. aureus", "H. impetoginosa", 
"H. ochraceus", "H. roseoalba"), blooming = c("Yes", "No", "Only last year", 
"Yes"), Location = c("SP", "SP", "MS", "DF"), Tmax = c(29L, 34L, 
32L, 37L), Cmax = c(35L, 28L, 27L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may get the `sum` of a logical vector to count

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Location) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(blooming == 'Yes', na.rm = TRUE))
```